# During svn to git migration commit authors have wrong email

Tags: git, git-svn, subgit

I have migrated my svn repo to local git. For some reason all authors look like:

```
userid <userid@localhost>
```

Is there way to change all authors rewriting **"localhost"** to **"myorg.org"**

```
userid <userid@myorg.org>
```

**UPDATE**

userid is not fixed.

Comment: What tool did you use to convert the repo from Subversion to Git?

Comment: SubGit one-time conversion takes a `--authors-file FILE` option to supply a file that maps subversion committers to full Git authors/email.  You'll probably have to run your conversion again, but this time specifying an authors-file.  See this helper for the mirror mode translation: http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html#6

Comment: in fact it did load authors correctly (except mentione issue) without any extra manipulations @Wolf

Comment: SubGit uses core.defaultDomain option as a domain to form an e-mail when it cannot find SVN author in authors.txt. Does the author have non-ASCII characters (it can be encoding issue, for example)? (Disclaimer: I'm one of SubGit developers)

Comment: nice that worked thanks @DmitryPavlenko

Comment: @DmitryPavlenko I have an issue trying to push to my remote repo. It seems there is a push hook. I get "invalide commiter" exception even though authors looks fine. Is there ways to set both be equal? In fact I dont even see comiter info, only author.

Comment: Could you please file and issue in our (https://issues.tmatesoft.com/issues/SGT) tracker and attach logs from subgit/logs directory (mainly daemon.0.log) with the exception? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments have several suggestions for fixing this during the import process.  If you want to fix it *after* the import is complete, you can use the `git filter-branch` command to rewrite author emails.

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
  GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=${GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL/localhost/myorg.org}
  GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=${GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL/localhost/myorg.org}
'
```

This will subsitute `myorg.org` for `localhost` in all author and committer emails (on the current branch).

Comment: (Note that the search/replace syntax used here is `bash`-ism)

Comment: I'm getting `eval: Bad substitution` error on line 2 when trying to use it. This one works https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/ but I can't make the bash substitutions work :(

Comment: .. or not: it worked once but now I'm stuck with `2: eval: Bad substitution`

Comment: It sounds like you're not using bash?  You could try something similar using a construct appropriate for your shell (e.g., using `echo` and `sed`, or something similar).

Comment: Since there were 4 authors in the repo I went with the linked GH script. Still I'd love to know what happened. I do use bash. I tried passing the argument directly to eval -- it works.

Comment: Running `$ git filter-branch -f --env-filter 'echo $SHELL'` results in output like `Rewrite d256d077ef4eeaa54cbfb0814060c786b4bae25a (1/52) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    /bin/bash`

Comment: On Windows, you have to use Git Bash to run the script. A more complete version can be found there: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/